# mysql procedure error

Tags: mysql, procedure

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()

     BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE b, c INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT empid FROM test.mytable;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
   OPEN cur1;

   read_loop: LOOP
   FETCH cur1 INTO b;
   IF done THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO test.test_log VALUES (b,'test');
    CLOSE cur1;
  END $$
```

When compiling this code I an getting 1064  error can some one pls help me to find the error

Comment: You probably want to copy the exact error and include what you have checked already (what did you find on the internet/in reference ... did you try that and what was the result)

Comment: @ashmysql Error codes say alot more than just giving a number, it's fair to say mysql is at least in that stage to point out to the start of line where you are getting error...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help u. Put END LOOP; before CLOSE cur1;